# Backup my app data

Tags: android, backup

I've got an application that lets the user make objects of type 'Kind'. In this objects, there are fields like id, date or name. There is also a field called 'bildid' which contains a path to an image on the phone.

All these data are written to a SqLite database. What would be the best way to let the user backup data? There are also some private data, a backup on the mobile phone would be the best. 
So how to backup the data, especially the links to my images that they can be used in a different mobile phone?

Comment: Zip everything? http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html

Answer (score 0):

Just zip the whole sql database and let the user choose a folder on the sdcard to safe it.

Comment: Do you know if its possible to use it on a different phone then? Is the path to images always the same in Android?